# How to host a web site on windows phone?

Tags: 8.1, wifi

I am starting my evaluation of windows phone features.
At the moment I am curious if it is possible to host an asp.net web site on windows phone with windows 8.1 OS. I would like to acceess this site over wifi. Could you advise some helpful sites with demo, labs or code snippents?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to host an asp site on a windows phone? Might make more sense to look into Windows for IoT, maybe on a raspberry pi.

Comment: I am looking for a way to manage win phone content over remote web site which can be accessible within a WiFi where the phone is registered. For example there is an application that doing files transfer: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/wi-fi-file-sharer/9wzdncrcx2jb . I would like to get how it works and make something similar

Comment: In this case this would be a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it's possible for an app to listen for connections from the local WiFi networks for as long as the app is active. However, doing so would seriously affect the battery performance, and also stop working once a different app was brought to the foreground.

If you did want to pursue developing such an app yourself, then I'd suggest looking for examples on [MSDN](http://dev.windowsphone.com) or asking on our sister site for [questions relating to development](http://www.stackoverflow.com)